# Is my facebook posting API correct?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to get my app to post to a Facebook group. I have granted the app the user_groups and publish_actions permission. When I call this function, there is no response action and the item isn't published to the group.

Is there something wrong with the snytax?

The code is:

```
function testGraph() {

    var body = "Test";
    var myname = "MyName";
    var myLink = "www.link.com";
    var myDescr = "A description.";

    FB.api('/523291487745000/feed', 'post', {
        privacy: {
            "value": "EVERYONE"
        },
        message: body,
        name: myname,
        link: myLInk,
        description: myDescr
    }, function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert(response.error);
        } else {
            alert('Message sent apparently');
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: The privacy parameter is not mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/#posts), and it does not make sense when posting to a group, because the group settings determine who can see the post. So try without it. And log the whole response object to your browser’s console.